# Android initialize View to main screen

Tags: java, android, null

I am trying to come back to my main application screen after I check permission (API 23) but I get the next error

> android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
>                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar

This is the code line -

> `Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

I think this is happened because my view is not initialized correctly. Now it's set to null.

If it's the right case can someone help me to understand the failed and help me to fix that. Thanks.

Comment: How are you initializing `view`? can you share the code?

Comment: @user13 it's in the post

Comment: @antonio The view right now not initialize it's null (private View view;)

Comment: can you reference view.getContext(), or getActivity()

Comment: Then of course it gives an error, you need to initialize it!

Comment: @user13 I use the Snackbar as dependencies "compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'"

Comment: @antonio Yes, but how I initialize it to my main activity view ?

Comment: `view = findViewById(R.id.yourviewid);`

Comment: @antonio I am not sure what to reference to ?

Comment: Then you need to show more code. Your layout.xml and your Activity